# Roblox Bug Report GUI

Tags: report, roblox

I need to make a GUI that allows the user to enter a bug report for the game. I don't know how I can make it so that it saves it to a file or script, so that I can read them from Studio or a GUI only I can view whilst in game. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [HttpService](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/HttpService) to save and load data on an external webserver.

Or use the [DataStore](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Data_store)